# TypeScript decorator for setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-decorator

I've started to learn how to implement TypeScript decorator in my application.
So I started with `setTimeout`. It's an method decorator which executes method after some time.

For example:

```
@Decorators.timeout()
 public someMethod () {}
```

Here is my implementation:

```
export class Decorators {

  public static timeout (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>): any {

    let originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    let decArguments = arguments;

    descriptor.value = function Timeout () {

        setTimeout(() => {

          originalMethod.apply(this, decArguments);

        }, 2000);
    };

    return descriptor;

  }

}
```

This is error I'm getting:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing `args` in your `Timeout()` function and you should pass those `args` to original method:

```
descriptor.value = function Timeout (...args) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    originalMethod.apply(this, args);
  }, 2000);
};
```

You should then delete this line because it's not doing anything:

```
let decArguments = arguments;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the delay decorator in the utils-decorators lib:
Here is a link to the documentation: https://github.com/vlio20/utils-decorators#delay-method

and here to the implementation: https://github.com/vlio20/utils-decorators/blob/master/src/delay/delay.ts